# Handler undefined in function ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to update the state of the parent component. I implemented a handler in the parent and sending this using props to the child.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleState = this.handleState.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      current_state: "keypad",
      current_video: video1
    };
  }

  handleState() {
    this.setState({
      current_state: "video"
    })
  }

 render(){
        return (
          <div className="contentArea">
            <Keypad handler = {this.handleState}/>
          </div>
        );
}
```

Now I tested this using a div and onclick event, its working using this onclick. Now I want to implement this in some existing code but that not working. Its giving me the error that the handler is undefined. I've been reading a lot of answers on simular questions but i cant find out why this isnt working.

```
    export default class Keypad extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      correct_code: 1234,
    };
  }

  init_keypad(code){
    window.tries = 0;
    $(".key").click(function(){
        var n = $(this).html();
        $('.screen').append( n );
        window.tries++;
      // if 4 digits are entered check if its correct
      if (window.tries >= 4){
        var w = $('.screen').html();
        if (w == code){
          $('.success').show().delay(5000).queue(function(n) {
            $('.success').hide(); n();
          });
          this.props.handler(); //here it breaks
        }
        else{
          $('.error').show().delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
            $('.error').hide(); n();
          });
        }
        $('.screen').html('');
        window.tries = 0;
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.init_keypad(this.state.correct_code);
  }


  render() {
    return(
    <div class="keypad_wrapper">
        <div class="screen"></div>
        <div class="error notification">ERROR</div>
        <div class="success notification">SUCCESS</div>

        <div class="key">1</div>
        <div class="key">2</div>
        <div class="key">3</div>
        <div class="key">4</div>
        <div class="key">5</div>
        <div class="key">6</div>
        <div class="key">7</div>
        <div class="key">8</div>
        <div class="key">9</div>
        <div class="key last">0</div>
      <div>{this.state.state}</div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the Parent component and how it calls the `Keypad` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `this.init_keypad = this.init_keypad.bind(this)` in your `Keypad` component and you need to bind the `.click` callback to the component itself or refer to the component by a variable:

```
 export default class Keypad extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.init_keypad = this.init_keypad.bind(this); // <---- bind it
    this.state = {
      correct_code: 1234,
    };
  }

  init_keypad(code){
    window.tries = 0;
   const self = this; /// <---- store a pointer to the component
    $(".key").click(function(){
        var n = $(this).html();
        $('.screen').append( n );
        window.tries++;
      // if 4 digits are entered check if its correct
      if (window.tries >= 4){
        var w = $('.screen').html();
        if (w == code){
          $('.success').show().delay(5000).queue(function(n) {
            $('.success').hide(); n();
          });
          self.props.handler(); // <----- use the pointer not `this`
        }
        else{
          $('.error').show().delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
            $('.error').hide(); n();
          });
        }
        $('.screen').html('');
        window.tries = 0;
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.init_keypad(this.state.correct_code);
  }


  render() {
    return(
    <div class="keypad_wrapper">
        <div class="screen"></div>
        <div class="error notification">ERROR</div>
        <div class="success notification">SUCCESS</div>

        <div class="key">1</div>
        <div class="key">2</div>
        <div class="key">3</div>
        <div class="key">4</div>
        <div class="key">5</div>
        <div class="key">6</div>
        <div class="key">7</div>
        <div class="key">8</div>
        <div class="key">9</div>
        <div class="key last">0</div>
      <div>{this.state.state}</div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `init_keypad` function, at `this.props.handler()`, the `this` is pointing to `window` object.

To solve your issue, simply pass the `handler` as an argument to `init_keypad` function.

**Like this.**

```js
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.init_keypad(this.state.correct_code, this.props.handler);
  }
...
```

```js
init_keypad(code, handler){
    window.tries = 0;
    $(".key").click(function(){
        var n = $(this).html();
        $('.screen').append( n );
        window.tries++;
      // if 4 digits are entered check if its correct
      if (window.tries >= 4){
        var w = $('.screen').html();
        if (w == code){
          $('.success').show().delay(5000).queue(function(n) {
            $('.success').hide(); n();
          });
          handler(); //here it works!
        }
        else{
          $('.error').show().delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
            $('.error').hide(); n();
          });
     ...
```

working sample of your [code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mclean-kmcig?file=/src/Keypad.js)